# How can I send my current location to webservice periodically?

Tags: android, location

I want to send my current location info to database periodically on background. For example; Once every 5 minutes. The location must be sent in the background even if the user is not in the application. What is best way to make it? What can you suggest to me?

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private FusedLocationProviderClient client;

private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context;

    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);

    client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

            // You can send to your webservice in here.
            Log.i("TEST_LOCATION", location.getLatitude()+"");
        }
    });

  }
}
```

You should start it in Activity class.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 5*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

And you should add in Manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

Comment: For modern Android devices you'd need to implement an app with a  ForegroundService and the user needs to manually whitelists the app to be exempt of battery use optimization. This service would request and handle location updates and save the data locally or send to your backend. But that's too broad to explain completely in a StackOverflow answer, so you need to narrow down your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Pending Intent and BroadcastReciever.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me.

Comment: Glad to know @BarışSağlam Happy Coding :)